# Prevent transition if exception is thrown in OnTransitionStart in Spring StateMachine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have the following `StateMachineConfigurerAdapter` class (currently using spring-statemachine 2.1.3.RELEASE)

```
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "defaultSMF", contextEvents = false)
class MyStateMachineConfiguration extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration()
                .machineId("defaultSMF")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(new ContextStateMachineListener<>(log));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<String, String> states) throws Exception {
        states.withStates()
                .initial(GpsState.STATE_CREATED)
                .end(GpsState.STATE_ENDED)
                .states(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("STATE_CREATED", "STATE_UPSERTED", "STATE_ENDED")));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        var t = transitions.withExternal()
                .source("STATE_CREATED")
                .target("STATE_UPSERTED")
                .event("UPSERT_STATE");
        t.and().withExternal()
                .source("STATE_UPSERTED")
                .target("STATE_ENDED")
                .event("END_STATE");
    }
}
```

I tried using the Context Integration Approach mentioned in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/#sm-context) docs. I created the following class.

```
@WithStateMachine(id = "defaultSMF")
class MyStateManagement {

    @OnTransitionStart(source = "STATE_CREATED", targets = "STATE_UPSERTED")
    public void onTransitionUpsertState() {
        System.out.println("Transition UPSERT_STATE");
        throw new RuntimeException("Abort transition");
    }

    @OnTransitionStart(source = "STATE_UPSERTED", targets = "STATE_ENDED")
    public void onTransitionEndState() {
        System.out.println("Transition END_STATE");
    }
}
```

When the state machine is in the STATE_CREATED state and I send a UPSERT_STATE event, the state machine still changes to STATE_UPSERTED, even if an exception is thrown in the method that is triggered. The behaviour I'm expecting is that the state should not change and I'm unable to get this result.

The only way I can get the behaviour I want is to use the following approach inside the `MyStateConfiguration` class:

```
...

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        var t = transitions.withExternal()
                .source("STATE_CREATED")
                .target("STATE_UPSERTED")
                .event("UPSERT_STATE")
                .action(context -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Abort transition!");
                });
        t.and().withExternal()
                .source("STATE_UPSERTED")
                .target("STATE_ENDED")
                .event("END_STATE");
    }

...
```

where I have added the action method in the flow. But using this approach is quite cumbersome. My preference would be to separate the handling of the flow and business logic into separate classes. The Spring Context Integration would be the best approach but I can't figure out how to get the behaviour I want using this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual usecase? Why would you want to throw exception in onTransitionStart?

Comment: onTransitionStart was just an example. I could replace it with other annotations but the behaviour remains the same. What I'm trying to achieve is the same behaviour when using the action and when using the context integration i.e. when an exception is thrown, the states do not change. This is not possible with context integration currently